# How can I specify which dates I want to be valid in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on a web page.  I currently am using it like this:

```
$("input#txtInspectionDate").datepicker({
        startDate: dateArray[0],
        endDate: dateArray[maxDateIndex],
        daysOfWeekDisabled: daysWeekend,
        datesDisabled: datesDisabled
    });
```

`dateArray` is an array of possible dates.  `startDate` is set to the lowest in the array, `endDate` to the highest.  Then I use `datesDisabled` to specify which days in between are holidays for our office so that people don't schedule things for days we're closed.

Can anyone think of a way to instead just tell the datepicker which dates are okay to use?  So, instead of telling it a range and then removing weekends and holidays, I would like to just say, "Use date 1, date 2, date 3, date 4, date 5."  We have a web service that generates available dates, so I can easily get an array like this:

`var validDates = ['12/2/2015','12/3/2015','12/4/2015','12/5/2015','12/6/2015'];`

Comment: I don't think the plugin has any such method. You may have to generate the datesDisabled using the list of validDates as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  datepickerValidDates: function(validDates) {
    validDates = validDates.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
      return new Date(lhs) > new Date(rhs);
    });

    var startDate = validDates[0];
    var endDate = validDates[validDates.length - 1];

    var datesDisabled = [],
      currDate = new Date(startDate),
      lastDate = new Date(endDate);

    while (currDate <= lastDate) {
      var dateString = (1 + currDate.getMonth()) + "/" + currDate.getDate() + "/" + currDate.getFullYear();
      if (validDates.indexOf(dateString) === -1)
        datesDisabled.push(dateString);
      currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return $(this).datepicker({
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate,
      datesDisabled: datesDisabled
    })
  }
});

var validDates = ['12/14/2015', '12/1/2015', '12/4/2015', '12/5/2015', '12/6/2015'];
$(".datepicker").datepickerValidDates(validDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
<input class="datepicker">
```